# Cloudstack VM use more CPU than restricted

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, virsh, cloudstack

I have a private cloudstack cloud with the following configuration:

host server:

- ubuntu 14.04
- KVM hypervisor
- 2x 2400 MHz CPU (amd athlon 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4600+)

virtual machines:

- 1x 500 MHz CPU (RESTRICTED use of 500mhz only by cloudstack)
- ubuntu 14.04

When i utilize the vm with the `stress` utility to 100% the cpu of the host shows a utilization of 50%. So the vm is using one full cpu core of the host.

Is this a bug of cloudstack? Maybe of KVM?

---

UPDATE

this is vm configuration generated by cloudstack:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>i-4-118-VM</name>
  <uuid>0c795c99-5bab-46f8-a321-71e3e398036b</uuid>
  <description>Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>512000</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>512000</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <cputune>
    <shares>500</shares>
  </cputune>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <sysinfo type='smbios'>
    <system>
      <entry name='manufacturer'>Apache Software Foundation</entry>
      <entry name='product'>CloudStack KVM Hypervisor</entry>
      <entry name='uuid'>0c795c99-5bab-46f8-a321-71e3e398036b</entry>
    </system>
  </sysinfo>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <smbios mode='sysinfo'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='kvmclock'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/mnt/a5bb6304-61f7-3d9e-9706-1f447a6a5fdb/af0c4ab6-aaad-4990-9046-da6ac83a575f'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <serial>af0c4ab6aaad49909046</serial>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='06:0b:00:00:00:15'/>
      <source bridge='cloudbr0'/>
      <bandwidth>
        <inbound average='25600' peak='25600'/>
        <outbound average='25600' peak='25600'/>
      </bandwidth>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='10.0.0.11' passwd='-'>
      <listen type='address' address='10.0.0.11'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='none'/>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='none'/>
</domain>
```

I HOPE SOMEONE CAN HELP OR GOT AN IDEA!

Comment: If a car has a top speed of 60 mph but you restrict it to 30 mph, you're still using the car 100% of the time when you're going 30 mph. Whatever speed the CPU runs at, if you're using it at that speed, you're using all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing in that XML for the guest that controls CPU usage is <shares>500&;lt;/shares>. This is *not* doing what you might think it is doing. 'Shares' is a merely *relative* weighting/prioritization for the guest, wrt other processes. eg if you have 2 guests on the host and one has a shares value of '500' and one has a shares value of '100', then the first guest will get x5 the amount of CPU time as the second guest.

If you want to place *absolute* caps on the CPU usage, eg to say 50% of a host CPU, then you need to use the `<period>` and `<quota>` settings instead. eg period of 1000000 and quota of 500000, will restrict the each vCPU to only use 50% of a host CPU.